# Radare2 debugging - How to get into lazy imported functions?

Tags: debugging, linux, radare2, dynamic-linking

I have a linux binary that imports functions from an external library (shared object). The functions are [lazy loaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) and not available when rip is at `@main` or `@entry`. When i step into such a function (like `call sym.imp.<function>`) it goes into plt->got->linker->function. Doing this manually (step-into) is very time consuming and uncomfortable. None of the analysis functions (`aaa`) seem to register any functions (`afl ~ <function>`) of the lazy loaded library so there is no way to gather the function start address (until the linker fills the plt/got).

The only way i figured out so far is to break at the `call`, look up the mapped memory (`dm`) of the (now loaded) library and adding the offset of the function (gathered by directly/statically loading the library beforehand). This finally leads to the target function start address.

Even though this works i think its still too complicated for such a basic task and there might be a much easier way. I can remember that IDA/Windows allowed to prepare a static environment (load binary, libs, add comments, annotations and such) and once going into the debugger the initialization phase (linker) detected the prepared libs and asked to use/overload them in the dynamic session. There, you could easily set breakpoints on the functions and the debugger stopped successfully.

The question is: How to get into lazy loaded imported functions without going over plt/got/linker in radare2?

Edit:
Here is a specific example:

```
r2 -d /usr/bin/rar
aaa
db sym.imp.__swprintf_chk
dc
```

Then you end up in the `.plt` (twice) and then in `map.usr_lib_ld_2.27.so.r_x + 50055`.

Comment: Can you please share your binary and point to the specific locations. This way we will be able to give you the best answer.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sym.imp.*` symbols are pointing to the `plt` and this is intended. In order to locate a specific function of a loaded module/library, you need to use the `dmi` command and its subcommands.

To follow your example, in the following steps I'll demonstrate how to reach the address of `__swprintf_chk`.

First, open a binary in a debug mode. I'm using the *same* binary as you.

```
$ r2 -d /usr/bin/rar

Process with PID 8617 started...
= attach 8617 8617
bin.baddr 0x00400000
Using 0x400000
asm.bits 64
 -- This computer has gone to sleep.
[0x7f1f85401090]>
```

`__swprintf_chk` is part of *libc* so we need the library to be loaded in the memory first. By default, radare2 breaks before `libc` is loaded into the memory so let's quickly continue the execution until we reach the program's entrypoint using `dcu` (**d**ebug **c**ontinue **u**ntil):

```
[0x7f1f85401090]> dcu entry0
Continue until 0x00403000 using 1 bpsize
hit breakpoint at: 403000
```

Now that we are at the program's entrypoint, we can simply execute the following command:

```
[0x00403000]> dmi libc __swprintf_chk
235 0x001335f0 0x7f1f845c35f0 GLOBAL   FUNC  162 __swprintf_chk
```

We received the address of `__swprintf_chk` which is `0x7f1f845c35f0`. We can use radare2's internal grep (`~`) to take only this value:

```
[0x00403000]> dmi libc __swprintf_chk~[2]
0x7f1f845c35f0
```

We can also print it as a radare2 commands using `dmi*`:

```
[0x00403000]> dmi* libc __swprintf_chk
f sym.__swprintf_chk 162 0x7f1f845c35f0
```

And if you want to execute the command, simply prepend it with a dot:

```
[0x00403000]> .dmi* libc __swprintf_chk
[0x00403000]> f~sym.__swprintf_chk
0x7f1f845c35f0 162 sym.__swprintf_chk
```

As you can see, the address was added as a flag named "sym.__swprintf_chk".

For more help you can execute `dmi?` and `dm?` and read the help for these commands.
More information can be found in the ["Memory Maps"](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/debugger/memory_maps.html) chapter I wrote for r2book.